# Difference in convergence time IPv4 vs IPv6

Tags: ipv4, ospf, ipv6, eigrp, rip

Using protocols like RIP, OSPF and EIGRP, would IPv6 converge faster in smaller network like 4 routers?

Would it differ in bigger networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing protocol algorithms are identical for either IPv4 or IPv6, so convergence should be the same. There may be differences in an implementation on some router software, but that would be an implementation-specific difference. For example, IPv6 as the newer protocol may have a better, newer, faster implementation of the RIP algorithm on a particular router model.

Comment: But the IPv6 implementation could also be more buggy, because it is not that well tested. It just depends.

Comment: That is correct. I didn't go into every scenario, I just gave an example. Nominally, the convergence time (the question) should be the same because the algorithms are the same.